# Find out whether the answer to a question depends on a group

Tags: dataset, functional-data-analysis

I've distributed a questionnaire to four different groups of people. An example of a question in the questionnaire is: Do you want to be informed about financial topics through social media? Yes/no.

I want to find out whether the answer to a question like that depends on what group a person is in. Both variables are nominal (the group / the answer option: yes or no). Usually I use a Chi Square test to find out if there is a difference between two groups. This time there are four groups. Can anyone advise me what test I should use in this case?

Comment: well, you have a $4\times 2$-table, so you can still use a chisquare-test! Or, you can use logistic regression with groups as predictor and the yes/no-answer as response variable.

Comment: I dont understand your tag "functional-data-analysis"